# NHibernate transactions randomly not rolled back

Tags: nhibernate, transactions

I have a suite of integration tests that run inside transactions.
Sometimes it seems that NHibernate transactions are not being correctly rolled back. I can't work out what causes this.

Here is a slightly simplified overview of the base class that these integration test fixtures run with:

```
public class IntegrationTestFixture
{
    private TransactionScope _transactionScope;
    private ConnectionScope _connectionScope;

    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public virtual void TestFixtureSetUp()
    {
        var session = NHibernateSessionManager.SessionFactory.OpenSession();
        CallSessionContext.Bind(session);
        _connectionScope = new ConnectionScope();
        _transactionScope = new TransactionScope();
    }

    [TestFixtureTearDown]
    public virtual void TestFixtureTearDown()
    {
        _transactionScope.Dispose();
        _connectionScope.Dispose();
        var session = CurrentSessionContext.Unbind(SessionFactory);
        session.Close();
        session.Dispose();
    }
}
```

A call to the TransactionScope's commit method is never made, therefore how is it possible that data still ends up in the database?

**Update** I never really got my head around the way NHibernate treats transactions but I found that calling Session.Flush() within a transaction would sometimes result in the data remaining in the database, even if the transaction is then rolled back. I am not sure why you can't call Flush, but then roll back. This is a pity because during integration testing you want to be able to hit the database and flush is the only way to do this sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

I had an issue with using the Identity generator that sounds similar. In a nutshell, when saving an object using an identity generator, it has to write to the database in order to get the identity value and can do this outside a transaction.

Ayende has a [blog post](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/03/20/nhibernate-avoid-identity-generator-when-possible.aspx) about this.

Comment: Spot on, fixed the issue I was having. I ended up implementing a HiLo generator.

Comment: If that was the problem it indicates that you're calling session.Save() or similar outside the NH transaction. NH will never insert an object outside of an active transaction, provided you really have defined a transaction. But you code shows only TransactionScope, not the NH transaction, and that can be problematic.